# undefined symbol error but the symbol appears to be defined in the code VHDL

Tags: vhdl

so, i keep getting those errors and I don`t know how to do to resolve them because I have the definition of the component in the code. Those are the errors:

> ERROR:HDLParsers:3312 - "D:/licenta/multyv3/multy.vhd" Line 123.
>   Undefined symbol 'D'. ERROR:HDLParsers:1209 -
>   "D:/licenta/multyv3/multy.vhd" Line 123. D: Undefined symbol (last
>   report in this block) ERROR:HDLParsers:3312 -
>   "D:/licenta/multyv3/multy.vhd" Line 124. Undefined symbol 'Q'.
>   ERROR:HDLParsers:1209 - "D:/licenta/multyv3/multy.vhd" Line 124. Q:
>   Undefined symbol (last report in this block)

The errors are in the cell_4

```
entity multy is 

 port (
     x: in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
     y: in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
     p: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
       clk: in std_logic
 );
end entity multy;

architecture rtl of multy is
 component Ripple_Adder
     port ( 
         A:      in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
         B:      in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
         Cin:    in  std_logic;
         S:      out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        Cout:    out std_logic
     );
 end component;

 component FlipFlopPack

 generic(
N : integer := 4
 );

port(
   Q : out std_logic_vector (N-1 downto 0);    
   Clk : in std_logic;   
   D : in  std_logic_vector (N-1 downto 0)    
);
     end component;

-- AND Product terms:
 signal G0, G1, G2:  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
-- B Inputs (B0 has three bits of AND product)
 signal B0, B1, B2:  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
-- D flip flop signals (Qyout)
 signal I: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
-- D flip flop signal (Qxout)
  signal O: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
-- d flip flop signal for S
 signal S1, S2, S3: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
--  signal for p
 signal P1: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
begin

 -- y(1) thru y (3) AND products, assigned aggregates:
 G0 <= (O(3) and I(1), O(2) and I(1), O(1) and I(1), O(0) and I(1));
 G1 <= (O(3) and I(2), O(2) and I(2), O(1) and I(2), O(0) and I(2));
 G2 <= (O(3) and I(3), O(2) and I(3), O(1) and I(3), O(0) and I(3));
 -- y(0) AND products (and y0(3) '0'):
 B0 <=  ('0',          O(3) and I(0), O(2) and I(0), O(1) and I(0));

-- named association:
cell_1: 
 Ripple_Adder 
     port map (
         a => G0,
         b => B0,
         cin => '0',
         cout => S1(3), -- named association can be in any order 
         S(3) => S1(2), -- individual elements of S, all are associated
         S(2) => S1(1), -- all formal members must be provide contiguously
         S(1) => S1(0),
         S(0) => P1(1)
     );

cell_2: 
 Ripple_Adder 
     port map (
         a => G1,
         b => B1,
         cin => '0',
         cout => S2(3),
             S(3) => S2(2),
         S(2) => S2(1),
         S(1) => S2(0),
         S(0) => P1(2)
     );

cell_3: 
 Ripple_Adder 
     port map (
         a => G2,
         b => B2,
         cin => '0',
         cout => S3(3),
             S(3) => S3(2),
         S(2) => S3(1),
         S(1) => S3(0),
         S(0) => P1(3)
     );

cell_4:
     FlipFlopPack
         port map (
             x => D,
             O => Q,
             clk => clk
         );

cell_5:
     FlipFlopPack
         port map (
             y => D,
             I => Q,
             clk => clk
         );

cell_6:
     FlipFlopPack
         port map (
             S1 => D,
             B1 => Q,
             clk => clk
         );

cell_7:
     FlipFlopPack
         port map (
             S2 => D,
             B2 => Q,
             clk => clk
         );

cell_8:
     FlipFlopPack
         port map (
             S3 => D,
             p(7 downto 4) => Q,
             clk => clk
         );

cell_9:
     FlipFlopPack
         port map (
             P(3 downto 0) => D,
             p(3 downto 0) => Q,
             clk => clk
         );




P1(0) <= O(0) and I(0); 
end architecture rtl;
```

Comment: Associations are formal => actual in interface lists (like port maps). Here the formal is found in the component declaration while an actual is the signal connected to the port of the instantiated component. (You have the order actual => formal.)

Comment: It goes `port => signal` NOT `signal => port`. "Port" is the left hand side of a boat AND the left hand side of the `=>`. "Starboard" is the right hand side of a boat AND begins with 'S', just like a 'signal' which goes on the right hand side of the `=>`.

Comment: Thank you, now i understand my mistake :D

Answer (score 0):

The port names of the component need to be on the left side of =>

For example:

```
cell_4:
     FlipFlopPack
         port map (
             D => x,
             Q => O,
             Clk => clk
         );
```

This applies to all instantiations of FlipFlopPack.

Comment: If the OP had supplied a [mcve] you might have verified your answer and might have noticed the same thing occurs in other instantiations.